# Android database save

Tags: android, database, save

I'm using a database to store and read my data, but I am not sure when my database is saved.  I didn't find anything like `db.save()`, so should I assume that my database is saved when I close it?  Should I close it also in onPause() (for saving my data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Notepad sample is probably one of the simplest examples:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/src/com/example/android/notepad/NotePadProvider.html

They use an SQLiteOpenHelper, ask for the handle when needed, run the operation, and then assume the data has been written. If that's the way the samples do it, I have to assume that db.update() or db.insert() take care of the IO as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but I believe your database is updated and saved as soon as you update a record.

So if you have an adapter class that manages your CRUD operations, the db gets updates and saved the moment you execute the update command db.update or insert a new record with db.insert()